# Ondemand login with Keycloak and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

So for one of my own project i was looking for a Solution where we need OnDemandLogin

**What is OnDemand Login for our requirement?**

So we want to user free to navigate maximum part of the website but with certain restrictions Like User cant  Submit any form without login . So we want to secure button click . User cant submit any thing but can access the content posted by others .

**Technologies and their dependencies**

```
 "@react-keycloak/web": "^2.1.1",
 "keycloak-js": "^9.0.2",
 "react": "^16.13.1",
```

As we are using Keycloak in our React Based application and we already implemented it and everything working perfect but i was not sure how to secure the button click as well .
So with the help of Owner of this [project](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak) i give a try .

**How Implementations Done ?**

Created one React Hook

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
export const useAuthenticatedCallback = (callbackFn) => {
    const [keycloak, initialized] = useKeycloak()
  
    const authCallback = useCallback(() => {
      // Do nothing while Keycloak is initializing
      if (!initialized) {
        return
      }
  
      // if user is not authenticated redirect to login
      if (!keycloak.authenticated) {
        return keycloak.login()
      }
  
      // otherwise invoke function
      return callbackFn()
    }, [callbackFn, initialized, keycloak])
  
    return authCallback
  }
```

And then it can be use easily with  function

```
import React from "react";
import {Grid, Avatar, Chip } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useAuthenticatedCallback } from '../../shared/keycloak/KeycloakOnDemand'
// Tranding function component
function Tranding(props) {
  const yourCallback = () => {
    // The code you need to be authenticated to run
    return yourCallback;
   };
  const authenticatedCallback = useAuthenticatedCallback(yourCallback);
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid className="text-center" item  sm={12} xs={12} md={2}>
            <h4>Trending..</h4>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item md={10}>
            <div className="trending-container">
            <button onClick={authenticatedCallback} label="ClickMe"/>
                 
            </div>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

// export the component.
export default Tranding;
```

Now Challenge was how to use with ReactJS class ...As per ReactJs official Documentation

> Hooks are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle
> features from function components. Hooks don’t work inside classes —
> they let you use React without classes. (We don’t recommend rewriting
> your existing components overnight but you can start using Hooks in
> the new ones if you’d like.)

So Solution? With the help of this  [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525070/how-to-use-react-hook-in-a-react-class) ?

> So one solution is to create a component that uses the hook, and then
> use the component inside the class instead.

and here is the implementation

```
import { useAuthenticatedCallback } from '../../shared/keycloak/KeycloakOnDemand'
function AuthenticatedCallback(props) {
    const authenticatedCallback = useAuthenticatedCallback(props.handleTradeCallSubmit);
    return props.children(authenticatedCallback);
  }
class Posts extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
}
........................................
.......................................
......................................
return ( <AuthenticatedCallback>{authenticatedCallback => 
        <div>
            <NotificationContainer/>
.........................................
.........................................
.........................................
<Grid justify="center"  container spacing={2}>
                                <Grid item sm={12} xs={12} md={3}>
                                    <Button size="medium" fullWidth id="btnSubmit" startIcon={<SaveIcon />} onClick={authenticatedCallback} variant="contained" color="primary"> Save </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
...............................................
...............................................
}
      </AuthenticatedCallback>)
    }
  } 

// Map redux state to props
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    activeUser: state.session.activeUser
  });
  
// export the component.
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Posts);
```

So this is one way..as i am new in JS world ..Whats the issue with approach is i have to make changes in each and every React Class file to implement this feature.

Is their something i am missing in this approach and can we make it more  convenient and easy Like Something Plug and Play?