# How i can realize such logic with class components

Tags: reactjs

How i can realize this with class components. How i can replace hook useState in class components and where can I learn this.

```
 function App() {
      const [state, setState] = useState(0);
      const switchingTabs = (e, value) => {
        setState(value);
      };
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <AppBar className="bar" position="static">
          <Tabs value={state} onChange={switchingTabs}>
            <Tab label="tab 1"></Tab>
            <Tab label="tab 2"></Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <TabBackbone value={state} index={0}></TabBackbone>
        <TabBackbone value={state} index={1}></TabBackbone>
        <Content></Content>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use React hook in a react class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525070/how-to-use-react-hook-in-a-react-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn more on local state in class components here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

---

Regarding a possible conversion of your functional component into a class component:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tab: 0 };
  }

  switchingTabs(event, value) {
    this.setState({
      tab: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Container>
          <AppBar className="bar" position="static">
            <Tabs value={this.state.tab} onChange={this.switchingTabs}>
              <Tab label="tab 1"></Tab>
              <Tab label="tab 2"></Tab>
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          <TabBackbone value={this.state.tab} index={0}></TabBackbone>
          <TabBackbone value={this.state.tab} index={1}></TabBackbone>
          <Content></Content>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```